# Collapsing Toolbar & NestedScrollView invalid behavior

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- Rest of the code there -->

        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_iv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- FAB -->
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/favorite_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_rate"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Take a look on the following video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkWuh4UU6qM (Sorry for wrong orientation).

On Nexus 4 (5.1.1) CollapsingToolbarLayout works fine, on Galaxy S3 (4.4) it does not.

On Galaxy S3 scrolling of the NestedScrollView's contents works fine (card scrolls to the top under the toolbar), *// on Nexus 4 scrolls the content of the card instead of card. — fixed by swapping NestedScrollView and AppBarLayout positions.*

I use build tools 23.0.1.

How to fix it?

Comment: it may be a bug of NestedScrollView. I try not to use it

Comment: AppBarLayout is supposed to be the first child of a CoordinatorLayout. It will draw itself over content if used with a scrolling view.

Comment: @EugenPechanec thanks, that fixed the second issue. First one is still actual.

Comment: You can move the padding from NestedScrollView to its child view. Padding always makes problems when used directly on (Nested)ScrollView. `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` looks suspicious. Try assigning a fixed height instead. Try both suggestions separately, keep the padding fix after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add this attribute to the CoordinatorLayout:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```